# Recording video simultaneously with audio in chrome blocks on main thread, causing invalid audio

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

So, I have what I think is a fairly interesting and, hopefully, not intractable problem. I have an audio/video getUserMedia stream that I am recording in Chrome. Individually, the tracks record perfectly well. However, when attempting to record both, one blocks the main thread, hosing the other. I know that there is a way to resolve this. [Muaz Khan](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/) has a few demos that seem to work without blocking.

Audio is recorded via the [web audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). I am piping the audio track into a processor node which converts it to a 16b mono channel and streams it to a node.js server.

Video is recorded via the usual canvas hack and [Whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy). When recording, video frames are drawn to a canvas and then the resulting image data is pushed into a frames array which is later encoded into a webm container by Whammy, subsequently uploaded to the node.js server.

The two are then muxed together via ffmpeg server-side and the result stored.

The ideas I've had so far are:

- Delegate one to a worker thread. Unfortunately both the canvas and the stream are members of the DOM as far as I know.
- Install headless browser in node.js and establish an rtc connection with the client, thereby exposing the entire stream server-side

The entire situation will eventually be solved by [Audio Worker implementation](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/113). The working group seems to have stalled  public progress updates on that while things are shuffled around a bit though.

Any suggestions for resolving the thread blocking?

Web Audio Connections:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var node = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
node.onaudioprocess = audioProcess;
source.connect(node);
node.connect(context.destination);
```

Web Audio Processing:

```
if (!recording.audio) return;
var leftChannel = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
Socket.emit('record-audio', convertFloat32ToInt16(leftChannel));
```

Video Frame Buffering:

```
if (recording.video) {
players.canvas.context.fillRect(0, 0, players.video.width, players.video.height);
players.canvas.context.drawImage(players.video.element, 0, 0, players.video.width, players.video.height);
    frames.push({
        duration: 100,
        image: players.canvas.element.toDataURL('image/webp')
    });
    lastTime = new Date().getTime();
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
} else {
    requestAnimationFrame(getBlob);
}
```

Update: I've since managed to stop the two operations from completely blocking one another, but it's still doing it enough to distort my audio.

Comment: This is a problem I ran into on some weaker machines myself. The way I corrected it was not to do ANY processing of the packets(audio and video) until after they hit my server., The only processing you should do before shipping it off to your server is changing your dataURL to a jpeg. I would not do any media stuff like Whammy unless you are utilizing asm.js

Comment: I've definitely moved more in that direction since I made the post. I've since gotten it to stop completely blocking, but it's still doing it enough to distort my audio. Are you streaming your audio and you video frames, or are you sending them over whole?

Comment: I ended up ultimately doing a peer connection to a server(to allow weaker clients, like phones). However, [Here is the code I used](https://github.com/Computician/WebSocketWebRTCRecorders/tree/master/Scripts) when grabbing the buffers and frames. It could be improved through moving the URI to View canvas code to an asm.js function.

Comment: You can also cut down on CPU usage if you make your jpeg lower quality and your canvas smaller on which you capture the video frames.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, I guess the problem might also be, using `requestAnimationFrame` for next video frame, I use a `setInterval(fn, 1000/frameRate)`, this way you have a better control over frame rate...

Comment: may be `requestAnimationFrame ` calling a heavy process repeatedly is the problem...

Comment: requestAnimationFrame often tries to run at the monitor's refresh rate, which tends to be around 60Hz. You could try just capturing every other frame.

Comment: Also, have you tried increasing the buffer size for the ScriptProcessorNode? It seems sort of obvious, but I didn't see it mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I think I would use setInterval rather than using requestAnimationFrame and (maybe) throwing out every other frame. requestAnimationFrame usually stops running if the user switches to another tab. You probably want it to continue recording if the tab isn't visible.

Comment: I have switched to using setInterval rather than requestAnimationFrame for better framerate control. In my implementation, however, tabs are a non-issue. Didn't know that it would stall on tab-switch though

Comment: Why not use the MediaStream Recording API and avoid the canvas hack?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Chromium project hasn't implemented the media recorder specifications yet. I am using MediaRecorder to service Mozilla browsers, however, and it works beautifully. There's still the odd issue of MediaRecorder API generated audio and Vimeo's transcoders not playing nicely together. I will eventually have to sit those two down in a room and work things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few key things that allow for successful getUserMedia recording in Chrome at the moment, as taken from a conglomeration of information gleaned from the helpful comments attached to the original question and my own experience.

1. When harvesting data from the recording canvas, encode as jpeg. I had been attempting webp to satisfy the requirements of Whammy.js. Generating a webp dataURI is apparently a cycle hog.
2. Delegate as much of the non-DOM operations as possible to worker threads. This is especially true of any streaming / upload operations (e.g., audio sample streaming via websockets)
3. Avoid requestAnimationFrame as a means of facilitating recording canvas drawing. It is resource intensive, and as Aldel has pointed out, can fail if the user switches tabs. Using setInterval is much more efficient/reliable. It also allows for better framerate control.
4. For Chrome at least, avoid client-side AV encoding for the time being. Stream audio samples and video frames server-side for processing. While client-side AV encoding libraries are very cool, they simply don't seem efficient enough for production quite yet.

Also, for Node.js ffmpeg automation, I highly recommend [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg). Special thanks to Benjamin Trent for some practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

@aldel is right. Increasing bufferSize value fixes it. E.g. `bufferSize= 16384;`

Try [this demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/?canvas_width=1280&canvas_height=720) in chrome and record `audio+video`. You'll hear clear recorded WAV in parallel with 720p video frames.

BTW, I agree with jesup that MediaRecorder solutions should be preferred.

Chromium guys are very close and hoping M47/48 will bring MediaRecorder implementations! At least for video (vp8) recordings.

There is chrome-based alternative for whammy.js as well:

- https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/issues/43