# WebRTC : Chrome not recording video/audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, webrtc

I am trying to recording audio and video from a webcam. I stumbled upon [HTML5 getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) and further googling led me to [WebRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/) [Oh! This is really cool by the way].

I implemented it and its working fine on firefox, able to record both audio and video perfectly.But On chrome either the audio or the video gets recorded depending on the configuration passed. Further googling led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217361/recording-video-simultaneously-with-audio-in-chrome-blocks-on-main-thread-causi), which clearly says that one thread blocks the other. Now i've seen demos for chrome that demonstrate both audio video capture simultaneously.

This is what my code looks like:

```
// Start recording
captureUserMedia(function(stream) {
                    localStream = stream;
                    window.audioVideoRecorder = window.RecordRTC(stream, {
                        type : 'video/webm'
                    });
                    window.audioVideoRecorder.startRecording();
                });

// Stop recording
window.audioVideoRecorder.stopRecording(function(url) {
                    videoElement.src = url;

                    videoElement.onended = function() {
                        videoElement.pause();
                        videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(audioVideoRecorder.getBlob());
                    };
                });
```

The above code is for starting and recording the media on button click.
The blob that i get back after recording when console logged shows `video/webm` for firefox and `audio/wav` for Chrome.

This clearly shows that one is blocking the other. Is there any solution for recording both or any other javascript that i am missing should be added to make it work.

**Update:**
As @mido22 suggested below that is the workaround. Link can be found [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/PHP-and-FFmpeg).

Comment: just a some extra information about Video recording using WebRTC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312505/record-video-and-audio-and-upload-to-the-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done some research on this topic, at this moment, there is no way get a single recorded file which contains both audio and video. The reason, it can be done in firefox is [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

I have not used RecordRTC, but suspect that internally, they use [whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) for `webm` recording and [recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) for `wav` recording.

So the simplest solution for chrome is:

1. record video as `webm` using first instance of `RecordRTC`.
2. record audip as `wav` using second instance of `RecordRTC`.
3. upload both to server and use ffmpeg to merge them.
4. provide a link that gives user access to the merged file.